# How to zoom in/out an image in a picturebox without changing its x,y coordinate data?

Tags: c#, emgucv, aforge, accord.net

I'am using the code below to zoom in/out an image in a picturebox, however after i zoom in and out the x,y data changes.  For example, before zooming out, when I draw a rectangle on an object in the image the X,Y,W,H will be 50,50,10,10
But after i zoom out a bit the data changes to 20,20,3,3.
Due to this the roi shifts. I need the zoom option as the image is a bit large.
BTW, im working in EMGUCV and Accord in a single project, so cant use the emgucv imagebox.

My code :

```
    Image zoom1(Image img, Size size)
    {
        Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(img, img.Width + (img.Width * size.Width / 
        100), img.Height + (img.Height * size.Height / 100));
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp);
        g.InterpolationMode = 
        System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
        return bmp;
    }

    private void trackBar1_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (trackBar1.Value > 0 | trackBar1.Value < 0)
        {
            pictureBox1.Image = zoom1(imgoriginal, new 
             Size(trackBar1.Value, trackBar1.Value));
        }
    }
```

Comment: That trackbar doesn't help you determine what the roi should be.  If you do it that way then you also need to be able the scroll the image.  So consider putting the picturebox inside a panel and change the picturebox' Size property.  The panel's AutoScrollPosition gives you the roi.

Comment: Hi, I didnt quite get what you meant. Can you please elaborate?